# Shiny: custom function does not work within shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have written a custom function that works when not in shiny, but as soon as I try to use it within my shiny app it returns an error

```
Error in rowMeans(data[, c:x]) : 
'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
```

So it obviously has to do with the rowMeans call, but I am passing a data frame to it, and I have changed the function to coerce the data frame to an array, but that has not worked.  I have also tried to put the function in several places, at the top of the server file, within the reactive expression, and also a 'helpers' file as shown in one of the examples, which is where I would like it to remain.

I have created what is hopefully a minimal example that recreates the error below.  Thank you for any help and suggestions!

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(selectInput('block','Choose Block',
                               c('1' = 1,
                                 '2' = 2,
                                 '3' = 3,
                                 '4' = 4,
                                 '6' = 6,
                                 '8' = 8,
                                 '12' = 12))),
      mainPanel(tableOutput("test"))
    )
  ), 
  server = function(input, output) {
    DF<-data.frame(replicate(24,sample(0:10,13,rep=TRUE)))
    block<- function(data, blocks){
      data<-array(data)
      month<-data.frame(seq(0,12))
      testy<-data.frame(month)
      y<-1
      b<-blocks
      a<-0
      while(y<24){
        a <- a + 1;
        y <- a * b;
        c <- y + 1 - b;
        d <- "block";
        e <- as.character(a);
        f <- paste(d,e, sep = '');
        z <- data.frame(rowMeans(data[,c:y]));
        colnames(z)[1]<-f
        testy <- cbind(testy,z)
      }
      return (testy)
    }
    output$test <- renderTable( 
     block(DF,as.numeric(input$block))
    )
  }
)
```

Comment: Investigate what happens if c:x is of length one, e.g. 3:3 or something.

Comment: I got it.  THank you, what a stupid mistake.

Comment: don't reassign `c`, its just asking for trouble

Answer (score 0):

I almost deleted this question as it only adds to my list of stupid questions, but I will leave it as an example for people to do more exploring and think about what your Shiny app is doing the moment it is called/initialized.

My above example doesn't work because when the app is initialized it is calling rowMeans(data[1:1]), and this is indeed only an array of one dimension not two.  I should have fully tested my function on all of the shiny calls I was planning before asking a question.